# Pork sausage patties in a crockpot overnight

Tags: food-safety

Is it safe to store a crockpot full of freshly cooked pork sausage breakfast patties overnight?  set on Warm. ? Also do you think this will make them "dry" to eat in the morning?  If it's safe, do you know any tips for making them keep their taste/texture ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how warm the warm setting keeps the food. If it's over 60 degrees Celsius, you *should* be fine, but for something like pork I would want it to be considerably over that temperature to be on the safe side, and then you're into cooking territory rather than 'keeping warm' territory.

You are probably better off cooking the patties, storing them in the fridge, and reheating them, wrapped in foil, hard and fast in the oven, if you're looking for a quick, convenient way to serve them first thing.